# Digit Adder In Java Not Working

Tags: java, digit

Examples of my output:

123
output: 5

111
output: 2

Lots work but ones like the above don't add correctly... Can anyone point me in the right direction? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitAdder {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    int input;
    int output = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    input = scan.nextInt();

    if(input < 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
        return;
    }

    while(input > 1) {
        output = output + (input % 10);
        input /= 10;
    }

    System.out.println(output);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not counting the first digit when your input starts with 1.

Try :

```
while(input >= 1) {
    output = output + (input % 10);
    input /= 10;
}
```

Comment: That works, but I don't understand why I need to say >= because if my input is 123, that is greater than one so shouldn't it work in the first place?

Comment: @user2803082 For 123, your original code only counted the `3` and the `2`. When you change `> 1` to `>=1`, it counts the `1` too.

Comment: @user2803082 After you divide 123 by 10 two times, you get 1, since `1 > 1` is false, you don't add `1` to your output.